# Create a "yearbook-style" multi-page layout of photos

Tags: graphics, positioning, margins, boxes, automation

I would like to create a "yearbook-style" layout of photos in LaTeX.  Each photo would have a caption and the objective would be to automatically layout the differently sized rectangular photos to minimize the whitespace on the page (with a mandatory margin around each photo and caption).  If I could do this with a browser as well that would also be helpful, but that is a question for a different forum.  I would have expected this problem to be solved problematically with some kind of open sourced package but I have found none.

[image]

[Survey of 2D packing algorithms](http://www.csc.liv.ac.uk/~epa/surveyhtml.html)

Comment: This sounds like an NP-complete problem.  Even if not, what you are after is likely quite difficult to achieve algorithmically.  Doing it by hand isn't an option?

Comment: Is there an algorithm that gives an approximate solution?  This seems like a very general problem with many applications, surely someone must have come up with some quick and dirty way of solving it (not manually).

Comment: Here's [something](http://pollinimini.net/blog/rectangle-packing-2d-packing/).  Google "2d rectangle packing", looks like there are some algorithms out there.  FYI I'm just commenting, there's no way I can personally help you with this.  Good luck, it will be interesting to see if someone can come up with something!

Comment: Interesting @ScottH. that is a good lead.

Comment: I bit off a lot with this problem, hopefully not more than I can chew.  How can an existing solution in a programing language be integrated with a LaTeX output?

Comment: You can embed python in LaTeX, an example is [here](http://www.texample.net/weblog/2008/oct/24/embedding-python-latex/)  If you can find some python code, you may be able to do something with it.

Comment: denilw, it would probably be better to delete your link only comments and add the most useful of them to the question itself. Possibly adding a note to seek help with implementing an algorithm.

Comment: Have a look at the following SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263932/packing-rectangular-image-data-into-a-square-texture

Comment: @denilw For the packing algorithm, you only really need the dimensions of the objects to be packed (and of the canvas to put them on). So I suggest a three-pass approach: First typeset every picture+caption individually, measuring the resulting size. Write this information to a file. Apply packing algorithm to generate placement information for the objects. Read that output again with TeX to obtain the formatted pages.

Comment: @denilw This surely means some more important pictures (because nicer, better, more symbolic, etc.) will end up in some edge of the page, and some not-so-great ones will make the centre. Wouldn't it be better to arrange them yourself in a composition software (or eventually in LaTeX)? Whitespace is not a sin but a blessing. If it's the number of pages you're worried about, you can downsize some less important pictures a bit.

Comment: My first thought is a list of pictures, and then doing permutations on width and height (sorted), and when placing pics on the "bin" (page? spread? sliced page?), to drop them off from the list(s). Placing with the info hsize/vsize, and something like the `\put` macro from the TeXbook. Did we have like a collection of test images somewhere which we could use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not complete answer to this question, it's rather showcase of idea I had about generative layouts and `luatex`. I don't think that any of following examples is useful as is,
but maybe in can serve as basis for more interesting solutions in the future, maybe something like [this](http://www98.griffith.edu.au/dspace/bitstream/handle/10072/33573/61942_1.pdf?sequence=1).

My idea is following: we have LaTeX command that stores it's content in a box ant then add list id and dimensions to the list.

```
\ProvidesPackage{generativelayout}
\RequirePackage{luacode}

\luaexec{%
generators = require('generativelayout')
genboxes = {}
curr_box_id =  2222
function findFreeBox(id)
  if type(tex.box[id]) == 'nil' then
    return id
  else
    return findFreeBox(id + 1)
  end
end
gen = generators.getGenerator("default")
}

\newcommand\gensavebox[1]{%
\setbox0=\hbox{\fbox{#1}}
\luaexec{%
local box = tex.box[0] 
curr_box_id= findFreeBox(curr_box_id)
tex.setbox('global',curr_box_id, node.copy_list(box))
table.insert(genboxes,{width=box.width / 65536 ,height=(box.height / 65536 + box.depth / 65536),box=curr_box_id})
curr_box_id = curr_box_id + 1
}
%\box0
}
```

Next we have environment `genlayout` that selects layout algorithm and run it on list of boxes:

```
\newenvironment{genlayout}[1][]{%
\luaexec{%
local gen_name = "\luatexluaescapestring{#1}" 
if gen_name == "" then gen_name = "default" end
gen = generators.getGenerator(gen_name)
gen:init()
}
}{%
\luaexec{%
gen:run(genboxes)
}
}
```

This package can be used like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern,generativelayout}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{genlayout}[]
\gensavebox{%
Hello world
}
\gensavebox{%
\begin{tabular}{l l}
hello & world\\
second & line\\
\end{tabular}
}
\gensavebox{%
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item First
\item Second
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
}
\gensavebox{%
little bit smaller box
}
\gensavebox{totaly small box}
\gensavebox{azsvm}
\end{genlayout}

\end{document}
```

Now the lua library `generativelayout.lua`

```lua
module(...,package.seeall)

generators = {}
empty_generator = {init = function() end, run = function() end}

function getGenerator(name)
  return generators[name] or empty_generator
end

printBox = function(self,box_number)
  tex.print('\\fbox{\\copy'..box_number.."}")
end    

generators.default = {
  init = empty_generator.init,
  printer = printBox,
  run = function(self,boxes)
    for k, v in pairs(boxes) do
       self:printer(v.box)
    end
  end 
}
```

Every generator is added as object with methods run and init, which are called form `genlayout` environment. Generator can be selected with optional parameter of `genlayout`, if empty, `default` is selected. The output is following:

[image]

We can sort the boxes:

```lua
generators.bigToSmall = {
  init = generators.default.init,
  printer = printBox,
  run = function(self,boxes)
    table.sort(boxes,function(a, b) return a.height > b.height end)
    generators.default.run(self,boxes)
  end
}
```

You can use functions from other generators, as `generators.default.run(self,boxes)`
[image]

More funny example of putting boxes on random places on the page:

```lua
generators.randomize = {
  width = 150,
  height = 150,
  init = generators.default.init,
  printer = function(self,box,x,y) 
    tex.print("\\put(",x,",",y,"){\\copy",box,"}")
  end,
  run = function(self,boxes)
    tex.print("\\setlength\\unitlength{1pt}")
    tex.print("\\begin{picture}("..self.width..","..self.height..")")
    math.randomseed( os.time() )
    for k,v in pairs(boxes) do
      local x = math.random(self.width - v.width) 
      local y = math.random(self.height - v.height)
      self:printer(v.box,x,y)
    end  
    tex.print("\\end{picture}")
  end
}
```

Here we use trick with `picture` environment to place things on exact place on the page
[image]

And finally, my port of http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2011/5/7/bin_packing/ to lua:

```lua
generators.binPack = {
  root = {},
  init = function(self) self.root = {x=0,y=0,w=280,h=250} end,
  printer = generators.randomize.printer,
  fit = function(self,boxes)
    local node
    for _,block in ipairs(boxes) do
        print("Velikost boxu",block.width,block.height)
        node = self:findNode(self.root, block.width,block.height)
        if node then
          block.fit = self:splitNode(node, block.width, block.height)
          end
    end
  end,
  findNode = function(self,root,w,h)
     if root.used then
       local right = self:findNode(root.right,w,h)
       if right then 
         return right 
       else 
         return  self:findNode(root.down,w,h)
      end
     elseif w <= root.w and h <= root.h then
       return root 
     else 
       return nil
     end  
  end,
  splitNode = function (self,node,w,h)
     print("Split box: ",node.x,node.y,node.w,node.h,w,h)
     node.used = true
     node.down  = { x= node.x,     y= node.y + h, w= node.w,     h= node.h - h }
     node.right = { x= node.x + w, y= node.y,     w= node.w - w, h= h}
     return node
  end,
  run = function(self,boxes)
    --generators.randomize.run(self,boxes)
    table.sort(boxes,function(a, b) return a.height > b.height end)
    tex.print("\\setlength\\unitlength{1pt}")
    tex.print("\\begin{picture}("..self.root.w..","..self.root.h..")")
    self:fit(boxes)
    for _,v in ipairs(boxes) do
      if v.fit then
        x= v.fit.x  
        y= self.root.h-v.fit.y  
        self:printer(v.box,x,y)
      end
    end
    tex.print("\\end{picture}")
  end
}
```

I don't think the result is really nice and I think there is some error in placing boxes on their exact place, but maybe someone will like it:

[image]