# How to get box dimensions within lualatex

Tags: luatex, boxes, dimensions

I'm new to lualatex, which looks phenomenal. I wonder what the easiest way is to access the dimensions of a box from within lualatex.  I intend to use it in more complicated situations than this (as part of lua chunks) so I'm not looking for a hack within latex that feeds the dimensions to the lua chunk. I'm aware of the limitations of \directlua.  Is this something that should be done using the node library?  How?

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{luacode}


\newcommand{\measureme}[1]{%
\directlua{-- what should go here to get the size of the box?}%
}

\begin{document}

The size is \measureme{this box}.


\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean the analog of `\settowidth{\alength}{this box}`?

Comment: Thank you.  That would be useful, also, but I'm looking for something more general than that, say something analogous to \settoboxwidth of the settobox package.

Comment: I want to assign the sizes of boxes to variables in lua so I can compute their optimal placement.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65601/2891, `\gensavebox` command in particular, it does something similar to what you want

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a way of doing this for boxes generated in lua instead of ones fed into it from latex, e.g. something like **x=sizeofbox({$y=x^2$ is quadratic})** but not necessarily with an argument that simple.

Comment: @JPi *“Is there a way of doing this for boxes generated in lua”* -- Each ``hlist`` and ``vlist`` node has width, height and depth attributes. See the manual, section 8.1.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\pc\@percentchar
\makeatother
\newbox\zzz


\newcommand{\measureme}[1]{%
\sbox\zzz{#1}%
\typeout{from TeX ht:\the\ht\zzz, 
                  dp:\the\dp\zzz,
                  wd:\the\wd\zzz}%
\directlua{
local n = tex.getbox('zzz')
print(string.format("from Lua ht:\pc fpt, dp:\pc fpt, wd:\pc fpt",
  n.height/65536,
  n.depth/65536,
  n.width/65536 ))
}}

\begin{document}

The size is \measureme{this box}.


\end{document}
```

demonstrates accessing box dimensions from tex and Lua, it logs:

```
from TeX ht:6.94444pt, dp:0.0pt, wd:35.33342pt
from Lua ht:6.944443pt, dp:0.000000pt, wd:35.333420pt
```