# Automatic box packing

Tags: luatex, boxes

I have a number of say, subfigures, of varying shapes and would like to waste less space displaying them; their order doesn't matter, and rather than having them all lined up on the same baseline I would prefer a 2D packing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\X#1#2{%
    \fbox{\hbox to #1{\vbox to #2{}}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\X{2cm}{3cm}\X{2cm}{6cm}\X{3cm}{2cm}
\X{2cm}{3cm}\X{4cm}{3cm}\X{1cm}{4cm}
\X{3cm}{3cm}\X{2cm}{5cm}\X{2cm}{6cm}
\caption{My rectangles}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Produces this:

[image]

I could use a picture-environment to manually arrange the boxes, but this seems cumbersome, I'd rather have an environment I can tell the maximum width and height and have it pack the content automatically.

This seems relatively straightforward using LuaTex (i.e. collect the boxes, measure them, run a rectangle packing algorithm like [Korf's](http://www.aaai.org/Papers/ICAPS/2004/ICAPS04-019.pdf) using the sizes, place the boxes at their optimal coordinates).

Has anybody implemented something like this yet?
I don't necessarily need an optimal solution, but I couldn't find anything in that direction.

Comment: Possibly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168748/optimal-arrangement-of-pictures-boxes-in-a-page

Comment: Oh yes http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65601/2356 seems like exactly what I'm looking for -- weird the search didn't show any related results for 'packing'

Comment: Of course, my answer there does not rearrange, which would indeed open up new possibilities for  optimization.

Comment: I would use your answer for i.e. images, but my boxes contain text/tikz graphics, and that would look weird resized. I'll try michal.h21's code, but I'm not sure if I like that algorithm's output…

Comment: I agree that resizing text is problematic in this context.

Comment: This is the 2D variation of the bin-packing problem ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762569/how-is-2d-bin-packing-achieved-programmatically. It is NP-Hard. One approximation runs nlogn. The reference points you to a C# implementation.

Answer (score 4):

I modified the code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65601/2356) quite substantially -- we don't have to mark every item in the environment specially, there's no need for a picture environment, we only use the temp box register.

The new `generativelayout.sty`: we create new lengths for the root box that can be set dynamically (I'm simply using all the available space). The environment collects its contents in a box which we unpack in Lua, no need to use a box register for each item.

```
\ProvidesPackage{generativelayout}
\directlua{gen = require('generativelayout')}
\newdimen\generativewidth
\newdimen\generativeheight
\newenvironment{genlayout}{%
  \generativewidth=\hsize%
  \generativeheight=\vsize%
  \setbox0=\hbox\bgroup%
}{%
  \egroup%
  \directlua{gen.process()}%
}
```

The new `generativelayout.lua`:

```
module(...,package.seeall)
```

We simply collect everything with a size, that includes hboxes, vboxes, rules, glyphs.

```
local function get_boxes(parent)
  local boxes = {}
  for n in node.traverse(parent.head) do
    if n.width or n.height or n.depth then
      table.insert(boxes, {
        w = n.width,
        h = n.height + n.depth,
        box = node.copy(n),
      })
    end
  end
  return boxes
end
```

The algorithm, largely [as implemented by michal.h21](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65601/2356)

```
local function findNode(n, w, h)
  if n.used then
    local right = findNode(n.right, w, h)
    if right then 
      return right 
    else 
      return findNode(n.down, w, h)
    end
  elseif w <= n.w and h <= n.h then
    n.used = true
    n.down  = { x = n.x,     y = n.y + h, w = n.w,     h = n.h - h }
    n.right = { x = n.x + w, y = n.y,     w = n.w - w, h = h       }
    return n
  else 
    return nil
  end
end

local function binpack_tree(boxes)
  table.sort(boxes, function(a, b) return a.h > b.h end)
  local root = {
    x = 0,
    y = 0,
    w = tex.dimen['generativewidth'],
    h = tex.dimen['generativeheight']
  }
  for _, v in ipairs(boxes) do
    local n = findNode(root, v.w, v.h)
    if n then
      v.x = n.x
      v.y = n.y
    end
  end
  return boxes
end
```

Instead of the picture environment we build `\vbox{\vskip<y> \hbox{\hskip<x> <node>}}` to position a node at `(<x>,<y>)`. The resulting node has zero size.

```
local function shift_by(n, w)
    n.width = 0
    n.height = 0
    n.depth = 0
    local g = node.new('glue', 0)
    g.spec = node.new('glue_spec')
    g.spec.width = w
    n.head = node.insert_before(n.head, n.head, g)
    return n
end

local function position_node(n, x, y)
    n = node.hpack(n)
    n = shift_by(n, x)
    n = node.vpack(n)
    n = shift_by(n, -y)
    return n
end
```

Position all boxes, packing them into a root box of minimal size.

```
local function output(boxes)
  local w = 0
  local h = 0
  local head = nil
  for _, b in ipairs(boxes) do
    if b.x and b.y then
      -- add node to the list
      local n = position_node(b.box, b.x, b.y + b.box.depth)
      if head then
        node.insert_after(head, head, n)
      else
        head = n
      end
      -- track extents
      if b.x + b.w > w then w = b.x + b.w end
      if b.y + b.h > h then h = b.y + b.h end
    end
  end
  if head then
    head = node.hpack(head)
    -- natural size was zero
    head.width = w
    head.height = h
    node.write(head)
  end
end
```

The entry point:
Like in the original code we could call something instead of `binpack_tree` to get a different layout.

```
function process()
  local boxes = get_boxes(tex.box[0])
  binpack_tree(boxes)
  output(boxes)
end
```

The test file generates a few boxes etc, notice we just throw any content into the `genlayout` environment; also notice how the `rule` depth is no issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{generativelayout}
\newcounter{piece}
\def\X#1#2{%
  \fbox{%
    \vbox to #2{\vfill\hbox to #1{\hfill%
    \stepcounter{piece}%
    \thepiece%
    \hfill}\vfill}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\hfil
\begin{genlayout}
\X{2cm}{3cm}\X{2cm}{6cm}\X{3cm}{2cm}
\X{2cm}{3cm}\X{4cm}{3cm}\X{1cm}{4cm}
\X{3cm}{3cm}\X{2cm}{5cm}\X{2cm}{6cm}
\rule[-5mm]{1cm}{1cm}
\Huge Hello!
\end{genlayout}
\caption{My Rectangles}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: this seems to fix issues in my code, thanks :)

Comment: @pascal looks like the code does not compile anymore. first error i get is "attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value (field 'height')" and when i work around this the next error is "You cannot set field spec in a node of type glue", for which i found on the net that glue_spec is not longer used in this way and that "g.width=w" would fix it. is there any chance you can have a look?