# Fixing error during collection of all boxes

Tags: luatex, boxes, directlua

i tired the code from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236066/16071) answer to arrange images loaded by `includegraphics` but got some errors i can not fix. the following code

```
module(...,package.seeall)

local function get_boxes(parent)
  local boxes = {}
  for n in node.traverse(parent.head) do
    if n.width or n.height or n.depth then
      table.insert(boxes, {
        w = n.width,
        h = n.height + n.depth, 
        box = node.copy(n),
      })
    end
  end
  return boxes
end
```

produces this error:

```
generativelayout.lua:9: attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value (field 'height')
stack traceback:
        ./generativelayout.lua:9: in upvalue 'get_boxes'
        ./generativelayout.lua:100: in function 'generativelayout.process'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\endgenlayout ->\egroup \directlua {gen.process()}
```

is there a way to fix this?

the code does not work on the proposed `fbox` nodes (in the example on the link) and also does not work on the nodes generated by `includegraphics`. of which node type the nodes generated by `includegraphics` and do they have a width and height?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Ah, good to know. I attend to optimize the arrangement of images loaded with includegraphics. Updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you optimize the placement of two dimensional objects, you are only really interested in objects which really extend to two dimensions and therefore need both horizontal (`width`) and vertical (`height` and `depth`) dimensions. Objects which only extend in one direction (e.g. whitespace) are not relevant. Therefore you can just make your test more specific:

Replace

```
if n.width or n.height or n.depth then
```

with

```
if n.width and n.height and n.depth then
```

to only look at nodes like hlists, vlists, and rules (in LuaTeX, images are internally treated as rules) which contain all three fields.